# LyX-LaTeX argument error \@firstoftwo

Tags: lyx, moderncv

I'm editing my CV with LyX 2.1.3 in Ubuntu 15.04. 
The following code produces an error `! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.` The error appears in LyX and also when exporting to LaTeX and running with TeXmaker.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands. %%%%%%%%%
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{John}                                     % required
\familyname{Smith}                                   % required
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                             % optional
\address{23 Main St. \#1}{12345 city, ST\\ U.S.A.} % optional
                                    % '\\' adds a line break
\mobile{+1(123)456 7890}   % optional
\email{myemail@email.com}  % optional
\quote{ }                  % optional

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\vspace*{-10mm}

% Contents of the CV that are commented out. 

\end{document}
```

The first question is how to fix this error in LaTeX?  The second question is if I can avoid LaTeX and fix this from within LyX?

I'd like to get into LyX with any tools or documentation.  However, I can't seem to find the appropriate one.  Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete as far as LaTeX is concerned, you will get `Missing \begin{document}`. It will not produce the code you say.

Comment: You cannot avoid LaTeX. LaTeX is the base, LyX needs it. LyX is an interface for experienced LaTeX users, as far as one developer once stated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  
I have included the whole ModernCV settings that I'm using.  The error happens in the \vspace*{-10 mm}.

Comment: As for LaTeX within LyX, I used "avoid" too strongly, and I also like knowing about LaTeX when using it.  I would -however- like to see a more robust LyX in which doing LaTeX configuration represents the minimal amount of activity.  Unfortunately, this hasn't been the case for me.

Comment: You cannot use a linebreak there for up-to-date versions of `moderncv`, use an additional argument: `\address{Walzing Wombat}{samba snake}{USA}`.

Comment: Yup.  That was it!  Thanks. 
I'm confused to why it was marking the mistake later in the file.  Mmph.

Comment: Looking at the parts of a model airplane, can you tell that parts won't fit in advance? LaTeX noticed the mistake when assembling the document, i.e. expanding macros and buildung blocks of text.

Comment: Right right, fair enough.  This has actually been more helpful than it looks.  Have a good one.

Comment: @Johannes_B can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful examination with the help of @Johannes_B, we found the issue to be LaTeX related and didn't have anything to do with LyX.

The template `moderncv` changed the arguments for the `address` field, and no longer allows for `\\` as was suggested in the comments.  Instead one should use curly braces for each new line.

```
\address{23 Main St. \#1}{12345 City, State}{Country}
```

For its identification, it was helpful to export the LyX file into LaTeX and run it there and see that it's the same error.